# Branch.io - switch between live & test deepviews not working

Tags: branch.io

When editing deepviews on branch.io I want to test them first on my staging site and only then use them on production. I tried everything, but every time I change something on test it also changes on live.

Is this working at all or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Brian from Branch here. When you create a template on the Branch TEST dashboard, a new template with the same name/key will also appear on the Branch LIVE dashboard. However, they are independent from each other and editing the template on the TEST dashboard will not affect the templates on your LIVE dashboard.

Please ensure that you are initializing your staging site with the Branch TEST key to ensure that you are retrieving the correct template design.

LIVE dashboard:

[image]

TEST dashboard:

[image]

Comment: `However, they are independent from each other and editing the template on the TEST dashboard will not affect the templates on your LIVE dashboard.`  
  
  
@BrianChang this is exactly not true in my case. Whatever I change on TEST, it also changes on LIVE dashboard.  
  

Here is also a response from your colleague via email:
`What you are experiencing is the expected behavior, as we try to keep deepviews the same on your Live and Test accounts, so you are always going through the same flow during your testing, as you would if you were on your Live account.`